# Delete item of listview when click on long press on listview item

Tags: java, android, google-maps, listview, android-listview

I am developing one application in that I am working with google map v2,I am saved five address  locations into shared prefernces in the form of arraylist.i used listview to display 5 address .Now i want to delete the item from listview when ever i long press on the particular item.For that i am using 'setOnItemLongClickListener()' on listview.

Here i need to get the array from sharedpreference and delete specific item what i want to delete ,i tried as like below .But it not working fine.please any kind of help

```
protected void removeItemFromList(int position) {
        final int deletePosition = position;


                    if(addressList.size()>0){
                    addressList.remove(deletePosition);
                    }
                    if(addAList.size()>0){
                   addAList.remove(deletePosition);
                    }
                    adapter.remove(deletePosition);
                    adapter1.remove(deletePosition);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    adapter1.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

            }
        });
```

my code

```
GoogleMap _googlemap;
private LatLng hydLocation;
Button clearButton;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private Editor editor;
private double lat;
private double lng;
public static ArrayList<String>  addressList = new ArrayList<String>();;
public static ArrayList<String> distanceList = new ArrayList<String>();;
public static ArrayList<LatLng> latLngList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();;
public ListView addressListView;
public static ArrayList<Marker> markerList = new ArrayList<Marker>();;
public static ArrayList<Float> latArray = new ArrayList<Float>(); ;
public static ArrayList<Float> lngArray = new ArrayList<Float>();;
private String[] addressArry;
private static int count=0;
private Builder alertDialogBuilder;
private EditText input;
protected String diskm;
private String distance;
private Marker marker1;
private Marker marker2;
private Marker marker3;
private Marker marker4;
private Marker marker5;
private Float lng1;
private Float lat1;
private ArrayAdapter adapter;
private ArrayAdapter adapter1;
private LatLng latLng;
public static ArrayList<String> addAList=new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<Float> lngList= new ArrayList<Float>();
public static ArrayList<Float> latList= new ArrayList<Float>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_or_delete_favourate_loc);
    addressListView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    clearButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clearBtn);
    _googlemap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.favarouteLocMap)).getMap(); 
    _googlemap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    _googlemap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    _googlemap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    hydLocation = new LatLng(17.3752800, 78.4744400);
    _googlemap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(hydLocation, 10));
    _googlemap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
     sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();


     /*addAList=new ArrayList<String>();
    latList = new ArrayList<Float>();
     lngList = new ArrayList<Float>();*/
    int size1=sharedPreferences.getInt("size1",0);
    int size2=sharedPreferences.getInt("size2",0);
    int size3=sharedPreferences.getInt("size3",0);

    for(int j=0;j<size1;j++)
    {
        addAList.add(sharedPreferences.getString("addr"+j,""));
    }


     adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,addAList);
     addressListView.setAdapter(adapter);

     for(int j=0;j<size2;j++){
         latList.add(sharedPreferences.getFloat("latArr"+j,0.0f));
     }
     Log.e("LAT", ""+latList.size());

     for(int j=0;j<size3;j++){
         lngList.add(sharedPreferences.getFloat("lngArr"+j,0.0f));
     }

     for(int i=0;i<latList.size();i++){
          lat1=latList.get(i);
          lng1=lngList.get(i);
          Log.e("LAT LNG", ""+lat1+lng1);
         latLng = new LatLng((double)lat1,(double)lng1);
         getMarks(_googlemap, latLng);
     }
     addressListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int pos, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+pos, 100).show();

                    removeItemFromList(pos);



            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onMapClick(final LatLng point) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     lat = point.latitude;
     lng = point.longitude;
     count=sharedPreferences.getInt("count",0);
     count++;

     editor.clear();
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(AddOrDeleteFavourateLocActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
    try{
         List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(point.latitude, point.longitude, 1);
         if (addresses != null) {
             Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
             StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");

             for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                 strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
             }
             final String strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();

             alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    AddOrDeleteFavourateLocActivity.this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Enter Distance From Your Location");
            input = new EditText(AddOrDeleteFavourateLocActivity.this);
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(input);
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {



                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    distance=input.getText().toString();
                     diskm ="\n"+distance+" km";
                     if(count==1){

                         addressList.add(strAdd+diskm);
                         latLngList.add(point);
                         markerList.add(marker1);
                         latArray.add((float)lat);
                         lngArray.add((float)lng);
                         editor.putInt("count", count);
                         distanceList.add((String)distance);
                         Log.e("DIST", distance);


                     }
                     if(count==2){

                         addressList.add(strAdd+diskm);
                         latLngList.add(point);
                         markerList.add(marker2);
                         latArray.add((float)lat);
                         lngArray.add((float)lng);
                         editor.putInt("count", count);
                         distanceList.add((String)distance);
                     }
                     if(count==3){

                         addressList.add(strAdd+diskm);
                         latLngList.add(point);
                         markerList.add(marker3);
                         latArray.add((float)lat);
                         lngArray.add((float)lng);
                         editor.putInt("count", count);
                         distanceList.add((String)distance);

                     }
                     if(count==4){

                         addressList.add(strAdd+diskm);
                         latLngList.add(point);
                         markerList.add(marker4);
                         latArray.add((float)lat);
                         lngArray.add((float)lng);
                         editor.putInt("count", count);
                         distanceList.add((String)distance);

                     }
                     if(count==5){

                         addressList.add(strAdd+diskm);
                         latLngList.add(point);
                         markerList.add(marker5);
                         latArray.add((float)lat);
                         lngArray.add((float)lng);
                         editor.putInt("count", count);
                         distanceList.add((String)distance);
                     }
                     adapter1=new ArrayAdapter(AddOrDeleteFavourateLocActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,addressList);
                     addressListView.setAdapter(adapter1);

                   for(int i=0;i<distanceList.size();i++){
                       editor.putString("dist"+i, distanceList.get(i));
                   }
                   editor.putInt("distSize", distanceList.size());

                   for(int i=0;i<addressList.size();i++)
                     {
                       editor.putString("addr"+i,addressList.get(i));
                     }
                     for(int i=0;i<latArray.size();i++)
                     {
                       editor.putFloat("latArr"+i,latArray.get(i));
                     }
                     for(int i=0;i<lngArray.size();i++)
                     {
                       editor.putFloat("lngArr"+i,lngArray.get(i));
                     }
                     editor.putInt("size1",addressList.size());
                     editor.putInt("size2",latArray.size());
                     editor.putInt("size3",lngArray.size());

                    editor.commit();


                }

            });
            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    --count;

                    marker1.remove();


                }
            });

             if(count==1){
                 marker1= getMarks(_googlemap, point);
                alertDialogBuilder.show();



             }
             if(count==2){
                  marker1=getMarks(_googlemap, point);
                  alertDialogBuilder.show();

             }
             if(count==3){
                  marker1=getMarks(_googlemap, point);
                  alertDialogBuilder.show();


             }
             if(count==4){
                  marker1=getMarks(_googlemap, point);
                  alertDialogBuilder.show();


             }
             if(count==5){
                 marker1=getMarks(_googlemap, point);
                 alertDialogBuilder.show();


             }
             if(count>5){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry You Can Add Only Five Locations", 100).show();
             }



         }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
private Marker getMarks(GoogleMap googleMap,LatLng arg0){
    Marker marker;
     MarkerOptions markerOption = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOption.position(arg0).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)).flat(true);
    markerOption.draggable(true);

     marker=googleMap.addMarker(markerOption);
     return marker;
}
public void clearData(View v){
    _googlemap.clear();
    //marker1.remove();
    sharedPreferences.edit().remove("size2").commit();
    sharedPreferences.edit().remove("size3").commit();

    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
    adapter.clear();
    if(!addAList.isEmpty()){
        addAList.clear();}
    if(!latList.isEmpty()){
        latList.clear();
    }
    if(!lngList.isEmpty()){
        lngList.clear();
    }
}


 protected void removeItemFromList(int position) {
        final int deletePosition = position;

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                AddOrDeleteFavourateLocActivity.this);

        alert.setTitle("Delete");
        alert.setMessage("Do you want delete this item?");
        alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TOD O Auto-generated method stub

                    // main code on after clicking yes
                    if(addressList.size()>0){
                    addressList.remove(deletePosition);
                    }
                    if(addAList.size()>0){
                   addAList.remove(deletePosition);
                    }
                    adapter.remove(deletePosition);
                    adapter1.remove(deletePosition);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    adapter1.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    /*Intent intent = new Intent(AddOrDeleteFavourateLocActivity.this,AddOrDeleteFavourateLocActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);*/

            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alert.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to save items in List's adapter in ArrayList. Also in adapter create method like this:

```
public void removeItem(int pPosition) {
    items.remove(pPosition);
    notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

In activity/fragment contain reference to adapter.
Implement ListView's methods setOnItemClickListener & setOnItemLongClickListener.

Comment: i removed items my problem is when i go back and come again to my activity still the list shows removed item

Answer (score 0):

You can use following simple line of codes.

```
yourItems.remove(poss);
yourAdapter.clear();
yourListView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

Comment: i removed items my problem is when i go back and come again to my activity still the list shows removed item

Comment: ok...do this
remove items from your *main* ArrayList and store it in a SharePrefence and whenever you came back to this activity,fetch your arrayList from sharePrefence and pass it to your adapter.:)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should implement these methods of activity

```
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle pInstanceState)
onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle pInstanceState)
```

Make your adapter Serializable (or Parcelable). In onSaveInstanceState pass it to Bundle as Extra.

After that in Activity's onResume call onRestoreInstanceState where you'll retrieve and set the adapter from extras.
In the Activity's onPause call onSaveInstanceState.

Hope this helps :)